# How can i improve my webpage performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a very heavy web page which contains a popup & this popup contains multiple tabs. each tab has multiple buttons on it. Click on a button opens a new popup which in turn opens a new popup. I am using RadWindow to open a nested popup. But, I am experiencing really bad performance. Is there any better way available to achieve this with or without using radwindow to disply popups.

Comment: It seems like you might have too many widgets going on. Follow the methodology of keeping it simple, if your page is going to get too complex, you are going to either kill the user experience or have users moaning.

Keep it simple and light and look at ways to improve useability.

Comment: I think my head is going to explode in a shower of popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you can do it load control on demand

i.e load control in rad window when you load it .

```
Control UserControl = LoadControl("usercontrolascx");
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(FeaturedProductUserControl);
```

that means you create you have tabs in the user control and dynamically load the usercontrol on tab. that will reduce load.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: [Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403590/what-are-the-current-best-practices-for-load-testing-and-profiling-asp-net-web-ap)
Step 2: Improve specific areas that need optimization

Comment: you could analyze whats going wrong using Yslow and take appropriate corrective action.